# Elasticsearch: time to index document

Tags: elasticsearch

I am updating existing documents by deleting and reindexing them.  I did it this way because the documents have nested components and it was easier to massage the document myself rather than construct an update operation.

Mostly this works fine but occasionally the system updates the same document twice very quickly.  I think what is happening is that the the search for the second update gets the original document (before it was updated the first time) because the the previous updates have not yet been reflected in the indexes.   By the time I try to delete the document (by id) the index has updated and it comes up as not found.

I am not doing bulk updates.

Is this a known issue and if so how does one work around it?
I can't find any reference to problems like this anywhere so I am puzzled.

Comment: Elasticsearch is NRT(Neal Real Time). It may take upto 1 second for your update to reflect. In the mean time, if you fire the next command on the same document then it may conflict. Share your code/command so I can see and provide you with a work around if one exists.

Comment: Have you try refresh api? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html

Comment: Hatim: Thanks, so I am on the right track that's what I really wanted to know.  There are several ways I can workaround this including refresh (thanks Lupanoide).    What I will probably do is preproccess the input stream to merge changes to docs.   If you "answer" this to say yes, this is expected behaviour then I will accept it.   I spent some time searching but did not find this spelt out anywhere so it is a useful addition to the knowledge base.

Comment: This will not solve your issue (updating twice in short period of time), but I just wanted to point out that you don't need to delete the document, as when pushing doc with same id the original one is replaced by ES by design (see [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/update-doc.html) for example).